# Incomplete MysqlDump Files - Mysqldump Inside For Loop

Tags: mysql-5.7, mysqldump, wamp

I am running a Windows 10 Machine with WAMP installed. I have also a Git Bash Installed. I was trying to backup all my databases in each separate file using the code below.

```
for DB in $(mysql -uroot -proot -e 'show databases'); do mysqldump -uroot -proot --complete-insert $DB > "$DB".sql; done;
```

The Problem is I am **only getting incomplete dump files** for all databases **except the last one. The last dump is complete.**

I have tried gzip the sql file by the following command

```
for DB in $(mysql -uroot -proot -e 'show databases'); do mysqldump -uroot -proot --complete-insert $DB > "$DB".sql; [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && gzip "$DB".sql; done;
```

Got the same result. Only the last database is getting dumped and gzipped completely.

Note: It seems the next iteration happens before the previous finishes. I have tried using wait and sleep inside but nothing works. I have also tried using mysqldump options --single-transaction, --force, --quick but none seem to work.

Comment: Which shell are you using? this does not look like a 'Windows Command Prompt'

Comment: a wait, 'Git Bash', I cannot access MySQL from 'Git Bash'... 

Comment: I am running this command from Git Bash. I could successfully connect and dump single database. But the above command do not work as expected. I have added mysql in environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a batchfile which runs under Windows. 
It will create the .sql files in the current directory. 
I left out Zipping the output.

The parameter '-N' will delete the header in the output from "show databases".

@echo off

```
set mysql=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\
set mysql=c:\progra~1\mysql\mysqls~2.0\bin\
set password=********

FOR /F "usebackq" %%F IN (`%mysql%mysql -N -uroot -p%password% -e "show databases"`) do (
    ECHO %%F
    "%mysql%mysqldump" -u root -p%password% %%F >%%F.sql
)
```

I only got 1 error running this script (besides the warnings... ):

```
performance_schema
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqldump: Got error: 1142: SELECT, LOCK TABLES command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'accounts' when using LOCK TABLES
```

Comment: I will check and get back to you here.

Comment: Actually, I made some tweaks from your answer and got the result. Sorry, for the `late` upvote. :D

Comment: Of course you made tweaks!, the example i gave was/is a minimal example... 